# Troubleshooting Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Earlier today, I was able to send snapshots to the Face API and get responses including faceAttributes describing emotion.
I'm using JavaScript via XMLHttpRequest.
Now, though I've not changed the code, I get OK 200 from the API calls, but the responseText and the response properties are both, "[]".
I'd like to troubleshoot to see what I'm doing wrong, but it seems like the only information available in the cognitive services portal relates to quota.
Where should I look for further analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an empty response if the API does not detect a face in the image or if the image file is too large (>4MB). You can confirm by testing with an image you know previously worked. To get the best results, make sure the face is well-lit and all features are reasonably visible.

Answer (score 1):

Hello from Cognitive Services - Face API Team,

I wonder the problem belongs to one specific image or all API calls?

For a quick check, you can try the image on the online demo [1].

[1] https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately doing the troubleshooting from the external perspective is quite difficult since you don't get any logs.  The most common steps are to try to repro your problem using either the testing console (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523b) or a tool such as curl or Fiddler so that you can see the raw REST request and response.

With one of those tools you can try to change up your request, try to call a different API, make sure there are no additional details being returned in the body or response headers, etc.

If all else fails please open a support incident from the Azure management portal and we can work with you.

We are also working to improve the logging and troubleshooting capabilities, but it may be some time to see improvements in this area.